# Feign client connexion

Tags: java, client, spring-cloud-feign, netflix

Heloo every body , i am trying to connect through a feign client to an api , i am using the feign client in a jhipster gateway .. i already used the same code in a microservice and it worked fine  this is the code i wrote :

```
@FeignClient( name = "berrycord" ,url = "https://dev1.digitalberry.fr/bcs-berrycord-direct/")

/**
 * This interface is used to call berryscheduler APIs ,
 * using netflix feign client
 * @param body  host to manage
 */

public interface TraceClientInterface {

    @PostMapping("api/v1/records/")
    public JSONObject sendReport(@RequestBody JSONObject report);

    // @GetMapping(value="/jokes/count")
    // public JSONObject sendReport();

}
```

```
@Component
public class UserFeignClientInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";
    private static final String BEARER = "Bearer";

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {

        System.out.println("test ========================" +template.request());
        System.out.println("test ========================2" +template.toString());
        System.out.println("test ========================3" +new String(template.body()));

        SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserJWT()
            .ifPresent(s -> template.header(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER,String.format("%s %s", BEARER, s)));


        SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin()
            .ifPresent(user -> template.header("X-Forwarded-User", user));

        SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserAuthorities()
            .ifPresent(authorities -> template.header("X-Forwarded-Role", authorities));

    }
}
```

```
/**
     * This service communicates with berryCord to create a send report POST
     * /api/v1/report/ endpoint, is called when creating or updating the host
     * resource
     * 
     * @param task
     */
    public JSONObject sendReport(JSONObject report) {

        log.debug("Request to create log report in berrycord ");
        JSONObject rep = new JSONObject() ;
        try {
            log.info("=========== Request to create log report in berrycord 2 " , report);
            rep =  traceClientInterface.sendReport(report);
            log.info("=========== Request to create log report in berrycord 3 " , report);

        } catch (FeignException e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
        return rep;

    }
```

```
feign:
    hystrix:
        enabled: false
    client:
        url: 
            berryCordUrl: https://dev1.digitalberry.fr/bcs-berrycord-direct/
```

But the connexion between the two is never done and i can't see results of the called API .. 
Who can tell me please what i did wrong .. and thanks :) :)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `@Configuration` as following and add `@EnableFeignClients` to your `Application.java`

```
@Configuration
public class FooConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public UserFeignClientInterceptor userFeignClientInterceptor() {
        return new UserFeignClientInterceptor();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response .. i have the same issue ... the client is never called :/ ... is there any other solution ?